# No such signal QComboBox::currentIndexChanged(string) (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to write a simple calculator. All I want is to connect 2 changable items in my widget (QCombobox and QSpinBox) and a function in order to whenever user changes the index of ComboBox or value of SpinBox, resulting value (I put it in Qlabel) is updated via this function. Everything seems fine, no mistakes, but when I run the program, it says

> QObject::connect: No such signal QComboBox::currentIndexChanged(string) in ..\zero\firewoman.cpp:30

Moreover, when I try to change the value of QSpinBox, it crashes

> The program has unexpectedly finished.

What may be a reason?

```
#include "firewoman.h"
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QSpinBox>

FireWoman::FireWoman(QWidget* parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    // declaration of combobox for levels of fire magic
    QComboBox* LevelFireMagic = new QComboBox(this);
    LevelFireMagic->addItem("Basic");
    LevelFireMagic->addItem("Advacned");
    LevelFireMagic->addItem("Expert");
    LevelFireMagic->setCurrentIndex(2);
    //  label to the left of the result block
    QLabel* NewLabel = new QLabel(this);
    NewLabel->setText("Luna's damage is");
    LevelFireMagic->move(100, 150);
    NewLabel->move(100, 250);
    // spinbox for obtaining the value for spell power
    QSpinBox* SpellPower = new QSpinBox(this);
    SpellPower->setMinimum(3);
    SpellPower->setMaximum(50);
    SpellPower->move(250, 150);
    SpellPower->setValue(5);
    // label that's for calculated damage
    QLabel* Damage = new QLabel(this);
    Damage->move(250, 250);
    Damage->setNum(80);
    connect(LevelFireMagic, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(string)), this, SLOT(updDamage()));
    connect(SpellPower, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(updDamage()));
}

void FireWoman::updDamage()
{
    int x, n, z, y;
    x = LevelFireMagic->currentIndex();
    int level[3] = { 10, 20, 50 };
    n = level[x];
    z = SpellPower->value();
    y = (n + z * 10) * 2;
    Damage->setNum(y);
}

QSize FireWoman::sizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(500, 500);
}
```

Comment: what is your Qt version?

Comment: The signal accepts an [`int`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged) not an `std::string`.  Note that using the [new signal/slot syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax#New:_connecting_to_QObject_member) will pick up these issues at compile time rather than runtime.

Comment: Yes `SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(string))` should be `SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int))` here: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged) closing as a typo

Comment: Qt Creator 4.13.1, Qt 5.15.1
Thanks, I put Int instead of string, and now message about "no such signal" has dissappeared. But when I try to change something, I got "The program has unexpectedly finished."

Comment: `QComboBox* LevelFireMagic = new QComboBox(this);` creates a new local variable created in your constructor. It shadows the a member variable of the same name in your class. So when your slots execute. `x = LevelFireMagic->currentIndex();` the `LevelFireMagic` pointer is a uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Many Thanks!!! The problem was using uninitialized pointers.